# jQuery: How to use percentage width of one element as a value to animate another element, and make sure it works even when resizing the window?

Tags: javascript, css

Here we get dynamic width of a percentage width element, and use `animate()` to apply it as another element's margin-left.

```js
function testAnimate() {
 var redWidth = $('.red').width();
 $('.blue').animate({marginLeft: "0px"}, 800).delay(3000);
 $('.blue').animate({marginLeft: redWidth}, 800, testAnimate).delay(3000);
}
 
$(document).ready(testAnimate);
$(window).resize(testAnimate);
```

```css
.red{
 background-color: red;
        width: 40%;
 height: 200px;
}
.blue{
 background-color: blue;
 width: 100px;
 height: 200px;
}
```

```html
<div class="red"></div>
<div class="blue"></div>
```

The code above isn't working when resizing the window.
Or we can make it work when resizing the window, as long as we don't use `animate()` to give it margin-left, but directly use `css()`.
But this doesn't solve the problem.
How should we modify the code to solve the problem?
And also, why the code above doesn't work even after I wrote `$(window).resize(testAnimate)` into code?

Comment: why are you trying to animate the left margin? are you trying to do some animation of one moving next to the other?

Comment: The reason I'm animating the left margin, is because I want to move that element next to the other.

Answer (score 0):

Use jQuery's [$.offset](http://api.jquery.com/offset/) function

```
var redOffset= $('.red').offset();
$('.blue').animate({
   top: redOffset.top,
   left: redOffset.right
});
```

if that doesn't work, you can try to give the .blue "position absolute" before you animate it.

```
$('.blue').css('position', 'absolute');
```

Comment: I've tried this method, but it's still not working when it comes to resizing the window.

Comment: By the way, the console said redOffset.right is undefined, so I used var redOffset= $('.red').offset().left + $('.red').width() instead.